# In NodeJS how do I exit a parent function from a virtual function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-async

I have something like the following

```
var async = require(async)

function start () {
    async.series(
        [
            function (callback) {
                // do something
                callback(null, "Done doing something")
                return // EXIT start() NOT JUST THIS VIRTUAL FUNCTION
            },
            function (callback) {
                // do something else if the first thing succeeded
                callback(null, "Done doing something else")
            }
        ],
        function (err,result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    )

    console.log("All done!")
}

// Start doing stuff
start()
```

Is it possible to exit the function start() based on some condition from within the contained virtual function where I placed the comment "EXIT start() NOT JUST THIS VIRTUAL FUNCTION"

Comment: Did you read the async docs?

Comment: WTH is a "virtual function"? Functions are quite concrete objects in JS :-)

Comment: There is no such thing as a virtual function in javascript

Comment: Perhaps let me rephrase. This type of function: function (callback) {
                // do something
                callback(null, "Done doing something")
                return // EXIT start() NOT JUST THIS VIRTUAL FUNCTION
            }

Comment: To finish your async series processing, just call `callback` in any function with error object.

Comment: you *exited `start`* a long time ago. that's probably not really want you wanted to do by "exiting start".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short yes, you can exit the task series early. `async` uses [error-first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/), which are a fundamental async callback structure in Node.js. An additional resource for learning about Async development using Node.js see this great [blog post](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/) from RisingStack.

Callbacks from `async` get returned to a final callback that is called when the [`async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) is completed if supplied, this callback is optional. If a task within the series returns the callback with a value other than `null`  in the first parameter, the error parameter, the `series` will break and return to the final callback handler.

```
async.series(
    [
        function (callback) {

            // If some condition is met, exit series with an error
            if (someCondition)
                return callback('exit start', null);

            return callback(null, 'Done doing something');
        },
        function (callback) {
            if (someCondition)
              return callback('error', null);

            // do something else if the first thing succeeded
            return callback(null, "Done doing something else")
        }
    ],
    function (err,result) {
        // Handle error returned from a series callback if one occurred      
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that in the doc :(

Comment: Is the early break actually an error condition, though? If not, you'll be essentially using exceptions / errors for flow control, which isn't a good idea.

Comment: @dvlsg passing a value to the the error param of the callback does not generate an exception, it just contains a value other than `null` which signals to `async` to break from the series. This is an acceptable usage of the error param. An error is not an exception, an exception can't be handled asynchronously and would require a `try/catch` which is synchronous.

Comment: I disagree. When I see `err` in a node callback, I expect it to be an `Error`.

Comment: @dvlsg if that were the case then why is async only validating that `err !== null` instead of `err instanceof Error` ?

Comment: Even `async` collaborators think it's [clunky](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1035) at best, and refer to it as a "fake error". It really is a misuse, but there isn't a better solution yet. Personally, I'd use `co` or `async`/`await`, since breaking early using either of those styles is more straightforward and supportable.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1064) for their proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

In `async` document (here: https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)

> async.series
>   Run the functions in the tasks collection in series, each one running
>   once the previous function has completed. `If any functions in the
>   series pass an error to its callback, no more functions are run`, and
>   callback is immediately called with the value of the error. Otherwise,
>   callback receives an array of results when tasks have completed.

So, instead of calling:

```
return // EXIT start() NOT JUST THIS VIRTUAL FUNCTION
```

You can just call:

```
callback("stop", null)
```

Comment: This works as well, but i can only accept one answer. Thanks though